# readline function: under the hood, python

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I am using `readline` function what happens under the hood?

1. The function reads one line from the HDD to a buffer in the RAM.
2. The function reads more than one line from the HDD to a buffer in the RAM.

   Thanks

Comment: well the name of the function is `readline`. I don't think that option 2 makes much sense.

Comment: @DeepSpace you may want to have a look at your system's IO then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caches all the way down!

Readline returns a string which might be buffered by:

1. The Python runtime,
2. The C standard library (stdio),
3. The CPU cache,
4. Memory, including virtual memory, which in bad cases could be disk!
5. Disk controller cache (only on servers),
6. Disk drive cache.

The dichotomy you propose has different answers depending on which level you're looking at.  For a disk drive, there is no such thing as a "file" or "line," so it will always read a "block."  Once a disk block (a few KB) is loaded into memory, it may as well sit there until the memory is needed for something else.  And the C standard library usually buffers a few KB at a time as well.

So a single `readline` call is likely to do most of the required processing for a few lines and only return the first one to you.

Of course, Python strings are dynamically allocated, which means the object containing the line will need to be stored in memory too, and in the case of virtual memory, some of that could also be on disk!